# validate edittext without triggering submit button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to validate Edittext field without triggering submit button. EditText supposed to be validate as user is entering data. I have the validator class which is working fine but how to invoke error messages without triggering save or submit button. I have looked at textwatcher and onkeylistener. But what would be the best way please help?

```
mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextUsername); 
if(mUsername != null && DataUtil.checkDigits(mUsername)) 
{ 
     mUsername.setError("enter one digit at least"); 
}
```

Comment: Talk is cheep, show us the code :)

Comment: mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextUsername); if(mUsername != null && DataUtil.checkDigits(mUsername)) {
                    mUsername.setError("enter one digit at least");
                }

Answer (score 2):

One of ways is that your activity implements `android.text.TextWatcher` interface and then you have to add `TextChanged` listeners to you `EditText` boxes.

Example:

```
  mUsername.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Then override `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` method like this:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// And you will place your validation code here
}
```

That will validate your edittext on any change (not on button click or touch).

Answer (score 0):

A TextWatcher seems the better choice.

```
final EditText mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
mUsername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(DataUtils.checkDigits(mUsername)){
        mUsername.setError("enter one digit at least");
    }
}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the difference compared to my answer?

Comment: Nothing really. I posted right after you did. We totally agree in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        //write your code
    }
});
```

This code will accrue when you finish entering your text in the EditText and that mean when focusing other view ... so this is the better solution because the validation will run when the user finish entering the input data rather then running the same code for every single character you enter.

Comment: I think that focus change solution is not a good idea because of that you have focus lost without changing text validation will be executed which is unnecessary.

Comment: Dont know really but when i compare this solution its execute the validation code less then TextChange listeners because on TextChange listeners the validation code will execute on every single character added or deleted form the Edit-text and that i may called unnecessary because the user did not finish his entry yet and the validation code is executing.